# {Align} keeps showing error messages and error "File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK" as well

Tags: align, bookmarks, eqnarray

I am trying to write a list of formulas below but this error message keeps appearing

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.614 \end{align}
```

This is what I have:

```
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}(P(t_{1},...,t_{n})) &=r_{P}(\mathcal{M}(t_{1}),...,\mathcal{M}(t_{n}))\in L,,\nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}(\bot) &=0  \mathcal{M}(\top)=1,\nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}(\neg A) &=\mathcal{M}(A)\rightarrow 0,\nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}(A\Rightarrow B) &=\mathcal{M}(A)\rightarrow\mathcal{M}(B), \nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}(A\textbf{\&} B) &=\mathcal{M}(A)\otimes\mathcal{M}(B), \nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}(A\textbf{\vee} B) &=\mathcal{M}(A)\vee\mathcal{M}(B), \nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}((\forall x)A) &=\text{inf}\{\mathcal{M}(A(v/x))|v\}\in M, \nonumber\\
\mathcal{M}((\exists x)A) &=\text{sup}\{\mathcal{M}(A(v/x))|v\}\in M
\end{align}
```

[image: trying to write this]

I tried to put $ everywhere where it could belong, but I dont think its needed in align, is it? Then the same error message with "{" appears. Changing to {eqnarray} environment did the same thing. Any suggestions?

Recently  it started to show this:

```
Runaway argument?
{subsubsectio 
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.91 \begin{document}
```

I am dealing with this by deleting the out.file.

Comment: Welcome! Make a small but complete example (l.614 suggests that you look at a bigger file than necessary). One way to construct the small example is to copy your file and comment out parts, step by step. You will find out when the error disappears. If you still have no clue of why, you can post that small file that still errors.

Comment: it looks like a fault subsubsection which produces a broke bookmark command.